# Unable to differentiate variable type inside loop in typescript

Tags: typescript, loops, union-types

I am trying to declare a list which can either be full of type 'a' data or type 'b' at a time. I understand why typescript is giving an error here, it doesn't know inside the loop whether the user data member inside temp variable inside the loop will be of type 'a' or 'b'. What I don't understand is how to fix it. I want an array that can be either full of one or the other type of data at a time.

error: Argument of type 'a | b' is not assignable to parameter of type 'b'.
  Property 'extra_porperty' is missing in type 'a' but required in type 'b'.

```
interface a {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}

interface b extends a {
  extra_porperty: string;
}

interface c {
  user: a | b;
}

const newList: c[] = [];
const tempList: a[] | b[] = [];
newList.forEach((temp: c) => tempList.push(temp.user));
```

Comment: Your easiest way forward here is probably just to assert that `tempList` is a `(a | b)[]`: `(tempList as Array<a|b>).push(temp.user)`.  Walking the compiler through the cases so that you don't need a type assertion isn't likely to be worth it.

Comment: Im beginning to agree with your argument Sir.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is assert that `tempList` is either an array of `a` or an array of `b`. 
That means the entire list must be all the same type.

What you have to do is define `tempList` as an array of either one of those 2 types like this

```
const tempList: (a | b)[] = [];
```

That will allows elements of type `a` or `b` to be placed inside the array.

Check out the working example in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20a%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20first_name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20last_name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20b%20extends%20a%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20extra_porperty%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20c%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20user%3A%20a%20%7C%20b%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newList%3A%20c%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20tempList%3A%20(a%20%7C%20b)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0AnewList.forEach((temp%3A%20c)%20%3D%3E%20tempList.push(temp.user))%3B).

Comment: Doesn't (a | b)[] imply the array could have either a or b in it at the same time? I'm trying to say the array will either have a or b type data in it.

Comment: it does. if you want it to have only one of them why are you placing the user which could be either one? An array of c could have both a and b users.

Comment: I think the better question is what are you trying to do?

Comment: I basically have a common function which accepts two different array types, but performs the same types of functions on them and then returns them. Now, I can write two different function and each would accept a different array type, but I don't want to do that, since it would  not be a modular approach. So I have a common function which can accept two different array types and output two different array types as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set optional parameters with '?':

```
interface a {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}

interface b extends a {
  extra_porperty?: string;
}

interface c {
  user: a | b;
}

const newList: c[] = [];
const tempList: a[] | b[] = [];
newList.forEach((temp: c) => tempList.push(temp.user));
```

Comment: Setting an optional parameter would be disingenuous to the b interface. extra_property must be present in b to make it b and have typescript check it.

Comment:  yes that mean a or b in c, when extra_property is present the value take de interface b

Comment: anyway, you are making a circular reference so it is wrong

Comment: Can you please explain, how I am making a circular reference?

Comment: The references and imports must be only one direction in this case you are extending to in b and then you are telling c is a or b but b is a but with more elements.